# Cleaning URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to cleanup my URL using mod_rewrite.

In my URLs I have:

```
http://blog.com/cat/post1/index.html
http://blog.com/cat/post2/index.html
http://blog.com/cat/post3/index.html
etc....
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I enter the URL mentioned above I get:

```
http://blog.com/post1/
```

But I want:

```
http://blog.com/cat/post1/
```

What am I doing wrong here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*) http://blog.com/cat/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Didn't work with me. Its still redirects to "http://blog.com/post1/" which is 404

Comment: Actually I have mutitple URLs that I wan to change (I edited the doc). http://blog.com/cat/post1/index.html, http://blog.com/cat/post2/index.html etc...

Comment: Hey.  I tried it out, it says redirect is in infinite loop and the page wont open.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually if I add (.*)index\.(php|html)$ to the second line it worked!  Thanks for helping me out!